# ios stripe not creating stripe customer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

This my index.js -

```
   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin')
  const stripe = require('stripe') ('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1');

  admin.initializeApp()

  const db = admin.firestore()
   const storage = admin.storage().bucket()
 const auth = admin.auth()

    exports.createStripeUser = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

  const email = data.email
   const uid = context.auth.uid

      if (uid === null) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
     }

    return stripe.customers.create({
   email: email,
    })
    .then(customer => {
    return customer["id"]
    })
   .then( customerId => {
     admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set(
      {
       stripeId: customerId,
       email: email,
       id: uid
        }
           )
      })
    .catch( err => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create Stripe  customer')
   })
   })

exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

const customerId = data.customer_id;
const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
 const uid = context.auth.uid;

  if (uid === null) {
  console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
 }

      return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
   { customer: customerId },
{ stripe_version: stripeVersion }
  ).then((key) => {
return key
 }).catch( (err) => {
functions.logger.log('Error creating ephemeral key', err)
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create ephemeral key: ' + err)
   })
  })

  exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

  const total = data.total
 const idempotency = data.idempotency
 const customer = context.auth.uid

  const uid = context.auth.uid;

     if (uid === null) {
     console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
     throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
      }

     return stripe.paymentIntents.create(
     {
  amount: total,
  currency: 'usd',
  customer: customer,
  payment_method_types: ['card', 'ach_debit']
     },
     {
  idempotencyKey: idempotency
    }
   ).then( intent => {
    return intent.client_secret
   }).catch( err => {
functions.logger.log('Unable to create Stripe Payment Intent.')
return null
  })
  })


    exports.fetchBankSources = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const customerId = data.customer_id

   const bankAccounts = await stripe.customers.listSources(
     customerId,
     { object: 'bank_account'}
   )

    return { banks: bankAccounts.data }
   })

  exports.deleteSource = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const customerId = data.customer_id
  const source = data.source

 return stripe.customers.deleteSource(customerId, source)
.then(res => {
  return {
    status: 200
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  functions.logger.log(err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to delete bank source: ' + err)
  })
 })

  // PLAID
   const plaid = require('plaid');

   exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const customerId = context.auth.uid
  const env = functions.config().app.env

   let plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox

  if (env === 'production') {
plaidEnv = plaid.environments.development
   } else {
   plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox
    }

    const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
env: plaidEnv,
options: {
  version: '2019-05-29'
}
   })

   return plaidClient.createLinkToken({
user: {
  client_user_id: customerId
},
   client_name: 'Bon Voyage',
products: ['auth'],
country_codes: ['US'],
language: 'en',
redirect_uri: 'https://bon-voyage.jonnybcodes.com'
    })
   .then((apiResponse) => {
const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token
return linkToken
   })
  .catch((err) => {
  functions.logger.log(err)
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create plaid link token: '  + err)
   })
 })

    exports.createPlaidBankAccount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const token = data.publicToken
  const custId = data.stripeId
  const bankAccountId = data.accountId

 const env = functions.config().app.env

  let plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox

   if (env === 'production') {
 plaidEnv = plaid.environments.development
  } else {
plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox
 }

   const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
env: plaidEnv,
options: {
  version: '2019-05-29'
}
 })

   return plaidClient.exchangePublicToken(token)
.then(res => {

  const accessToken = res.access_token
  return plaidClient.createStripeToken(accessToken, bankAccountId)

 })
.then(resp => {

  const bankAccountToken = resp.stripe_bank_account_token
  return stripe.customers.createSource(custId, {
    source: bankAccountToken
  }).then(bank => {
    return bank
  })

})
.catch((err) => {
  functions.logger.log(err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create plaid link token: ' + err)
})
 })
```

The functions show deployed in the console as shown below:-

[image]

This is my viewcontroller-

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in if error == nil {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
    
                }
 else{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
            }
      }
      Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email.text ?? ""]) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

It shows on the  Firebase auth console:-
[image]

BUT, it shows nothing on the Stripe Dashboard:-
[image]

what am I doing wrong ? As far as I know, everything is correct.
As the functions are deployed and it creates user in the firebase console, why is no customer created in the Stripe Dashboard ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the wrong Stripe account/have the API keys mixed up so it's created on a  different account that the one you're looking at? 
Try getting the Stripe Customer ID `cus_xxxx` from your database/logging it somewhere and then search for it directly on the Stripe dashboard.

Comment: I have only one stripe account

Comment: Any further information you need, I can give it  to you.

Comment: In the debugger it shows - po httpsCallable
error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: cannot find 'httpsCallable' in scope
httpsCallable
^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: So, it cannot find httpsCallable in scope. How to rectify it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey the code do not have an issue I face the same issue I fixed it by Log out or quit the simulator and run the application on new simulator.